# Invalid requests[0].replaceImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm trying to load an image and video into Google Drive and then transfer it over to Google Slides.

For some reason it doesn't work every time.

I'm getting the error:

> Invalid requests[0].replaceImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me "The access to the provided image was forbidden."

Comment: Post your code: minimal example to reproduce an issue. You sure your image is available for everyone on the web?